# I am getting a syntax error but i dont know why

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am on windows cmd

I was stating yarn for my node.js based app

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

How do i fix this

Comment: do i need to install an additional npm package for this?

Comment: this code assumes you are on linux or have linux commands defined on your OS ... notice that highlighted line is making a system call to command  `dirname` which is on linux ... the parameter fed into `dirname` does an echo on variable $0 which is the fullpath to the executing process ... then its output is piped into sed which converts a backslash into a forward slash probably to translate a windows file path into a linux path ... essentially its defining variable `basedir` with the directory holding the script which is getting run